# How to populate list when using SherlockFragment and SherlockTabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I've created my Tabs using this function:

```
public class MyTaber extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{

TabHost mTabHost;
private Tab1MyFirstTab frgTabMyFirstTab;
private Tab2Recipes frgTabRecipes;
private Tab3Products frgTabProducts;
private Tab4FAQ frgTabFAQ;
private Tab5Settings frgTabSettings;

private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myview);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new MainPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager()));
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    mViewPager.setPageMarginDrawable(R.drawable.border);
    mViewPager.setPageMargin(16);
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.tab_myfirsttab_title)
            .setTabListener(this).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab1_inactive));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.tab_recipes_title)
            .setTabListener(this).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab2_inactive));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.tab_products_title)
            .setTabListener(this).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab3_inactive));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.tab_faq_title)
            .setTabListener(this).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab4_inactive));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
            .setText(R.string.tab_settings_title).setTabListener(this).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab5_inactive));
}

private class MainPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public MainPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return (frgTabMyFirstTab = new Tab1MyFirstTab());

        case 1:
            return (frgTabRecipes = new Tab2Recipes());

        case 2:
            return (frgTabProducts = new Tab3Products());

        case 3:
            return (frgTabFAQ = new Tab4FAQ());

        case 4:
            return (frgTabSettings = new Tab5Settings());

        }
        return null;
    }
```

Each tab is created in similar way using SherlockFragment:

```
public class Tab3Products extends SherlockFragment{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3products, container, false);

    /*
    ListView list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvMySpecialList);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mySpecialKeys);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    */
    return view;

}
```

Questions are.

1. My first tab need to have 2 parts, upper part should be slider with 2 slides, and lower part should be a list with 3 Items. How do I inflate list within fragment. I've tried using ArrayAdapter (as you can see in commented code), and getting strings from StringArray, but that crashes my app with all bunch of android.View.coreographer problems.
2. When I tap on first list Item whole Tab1 need to change layout to similar halfimage / half list, but it need to be different fragment or activity.

   1. Because of 2. - Should I use SherlockFragment(as I do) or SherlockFragmentActivity for my fragments?

So, If anyone can help now, because standard lists and filling them do not work, obviously I'm missing some knowledge how fragments work and how to start different fragments/activities within same tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add fragments in fragments, as you can't add activity inside an activity. Your aproach is good. A fFragmentActivity to manage Fragments is OK

If you want so change fragments in your FragmentActivity, you need to **Add/Replace** them example :

```
AlbumGridFragment fragment = new AlbumGridFragment();
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.animator.anim_back_right, R.animator.anim_back_left, R.animator.anim_left, R.animator.anim_right)
                .replace(R.id.album_fragment, fragment).addToBackStack(MainFragmentActivity.ALBUM_GRID_TAG).commit();
```

This will replace the fragment with a list of album, with the fragment with a grid of image from one album, with an animation. (you can do the same with "Add" it ll **stack** the fragment on top of the other)

hope it helps